# How come typescript writes to file without open/close

Tags: typescript, io

All languages I know of do the `open-write-close` routine. But in typescript:

```js
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
writeFileSync(filename, "hello")
```

seems to work fine. How does this "magic" work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class of FileHandle contain the fs module that describe in this link:

[File system module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-filehandle)

Class: FileHandle

A  object is an object wrapper for a numeric file descriptor.

Instances of the  object are created by the fsPromises.open() method.

All  objects are s.

If a  is not closed using the filehandle.close() method, it will try to automatically close the file descriptor and emit a process warning, helping to prevent memory leaks. Please do not rely on this behavior because it can be unreliable and the file may not be closed. Instead, always explicitly close s. Node.js may change this behavior in the future.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, no explicit open is needed, but closing the resource file *is* needed

Comment: The best practice is closed files manually but  "If a is not closed using the filehandle.close() method, it will try to automatically close the file descriptor and emit a process warning, helping to prevent memory leaks"